# How to create MSSQL database 2008 (version 655) with MSSQL 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to create MSSQL database 2008 (version 655) with MSSQL 2008 R2?

In options you can set compatibility level to 2000/2005/2008 only, but there is no option to create database version 655.

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: I have a corrupted log file, so I need an empty database with exact version to replace MDF in emergency mode and then repair the log file.

Comment: As I have answered, I dont think you can change the version of your database. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** change or create the database version. There is no conversion" tool to change the database version or anything to do that. The best what you can do is to create your database on the other server. But under no circumstances you can change the version of your database.

Comment: I don't want to change version of database, just create older version database. I know, that I can do it on original server, but I want to save some time by doing it on my machine.

Comment: @filipbe:- `just create older version database.` I am not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: In this moment I have a machine with MSSQL 2008 R2 server running. I can create database with version 661 (which is 2008 R2), but I wanted to create MSSQL 2008 database (which is not 2008 R2, and its internal version number is 655).

Comment: @filipbe:- Ok I got that. You cannot achieve that. The only thing you can do is to make the compatibility level of both the database same but the version cannot be changed!